# A picture of the character of an induced representation

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

In his great video on induced representations on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jH7OcZYoOQ at min 14.05 Borcherds draws a picture of the induced character of a representation. The picture is as follows: we have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, now we take a character on $H$, and see it as a function on $G$ (vanishing outside of $H$). Then we conjugate this function by elements of $G/H$ and sum up all the corresponding functions on $G$ (the support of each such function is a subgroup of $G$ conjugate to $H$). The resulting sum is the induced character. The video explains all this in one minute.

I wonder, is there some book/lecture notes on representation theory where this type of picture is drawn? I've never seen it before.